# Allow Connecting to Ports On my Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I konw that it is probably a very simple question, but how would I allow someone from outside my network to connect to a speciffic port on my router? From what I understand routers do not allow anyone to connect to any ports, but I need to have a specific port open for a computer from another network to connect to me. If that process is router-specific, how is it called? Thanks!

Comment: Look for a section on your Router setup (log into the Router) for Ports or Port Forwarding and the setting should be there.

Comment: @John Thanks! I found the setting but there are multiple fields and I don't know what I settings I should put on each one. (screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/DvSzEbo.png) Can you help me any further?

Comment: Name = your choice; Protocol probably TCP but you should check; WAN IP - where the request is coming from; the other three you need to check your documentation.

Comment: @John Thanks! I found the correct settings and it seems to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a section on your Router setup (log into the Router) for Ports or Port Forwarding and the setting should be there

```
Name = your choice; 
Protocol probably TCP but you should check; 
WAN IP - where the request is coming from; 
LAN Host - may be name or IP address depending on router
WAN Port - Router Port
LAN Port - Network Port
```

Here is a screen shot of settings you should consider.

[image: Router settings for port forwarding]